# Event listener, classes and garbage collection

Tags: javascript, class, garbage-collection, addeventlistener

I just wanted to clear something up in my own head.

I have a Class with methods generating html. I also have a method generating an eventlistener.

I find the event listener only works once (when the button is pushed in this instance). I checked the developer tools and the event listener is removed.

it only stays and works more than once when I make the eventlistener callback recursive so the eventlistener is reapplied every callback.... like below

```
calculate(){ //class method
      let button_html = document.getElementById("calculateBut");// probably quite leaky finding this twice
      button_html.addEventListener("click", this.calculate.bind(this));// recursive binding of event listener and callback. need this because i think whats happening is the callback is being removed by garbage collection after the render_content() method is finished
}

//called in another part of the class
let button_html = document.getElementById("calculateBut"); //getting the calculate button after its creation
button_html.addEventListener("click", this.calculate.bind(this)); // binding call back function to scope of the class. not the callback function internal scope
```

I am fairly sure it either because of the global execution context being deleted off the call stack or something around garbage collection but please if im missing something please let me know

also if you think be should be doing thing differently, please let me know.

thanks is advance!

edit:

Full classes & main below:

Main

```
let toolPage = new TablePage(toolBut, homeUrl ,tool_dataUrl, tools_title);
let materialsPage = new TablePage(materialsBut,homeUrl, material_dataUrl ,materials_title);
let feedsSpeedsPg = new CalcPage(feedSpeedsBut, homeUrl, [tool_dataUrl, material_dataUrl], FS_title);





//event listeners -  have url hash operations for use later
homeBut.addEventListener("click", function(){window.location = "/";});//eventlistener for clicking te home button

feedSpeedsBut.addEventListener("click", function(){ //eventlistener for clicking te F&S button
  window.location.hash = feedSpeedsBut.innerHTML
  feedsSpeedsPg.render_content();

});

materialsBut.addEventListener("click", () => { //eventlistener for clicking te materials button
  materialsPage.render_content();
});

toolBut.addEventListener("click", () => { //eventlistener for clicking te tools button
   toolPage.render_content();
});
```

CalcPage

```
  

    generate_results(){ // create a container for results
      this.content_html.innerHTML += `<div id = "results"></div>`;
    }

    populate_results(fr,sd){ //populate the results container
      let results_html = document.getElementById("results");
      results_html.innerHTML = "";
      let feed_rate = `<div id = "feed_rate">${"Feed Rate = " + fr + "mm/min"}</div>`;
      let stepdown = `<div id = "stepdown">${"Step Down = " + sd + "mm"}</div>`;
      results_html.innerHTML = feed_rate + "\n" + stepdown;
    }

    

    generate_calculate_button(){ //generate button
      let button = `<button type="button" id="calculateBut"> Calculate </button>`
      return button;
    }

    calculate(){

      let button_html = document.getElementById("calculateBut");// probably quite leaky finding this twice
      button_html.addEventListener("click", this.calculate.bind(this));// recursive binding of event listener and callback. need this because i think whats happening is the callback is being removed by garbage collection after the render_content() method is finished
      
    }



    
    async generatePage(populate_dropdown, generate_calculate_button){
      //wiping previous page
      this.table_html.innerHTML = "";
      this.title_html.innerHTML = this.title;

      //injecting dd into html
      
      this.content_html.innerHTML = material_dropdown + "\n"  + tool_diameter_dropdown + "\n" + tool_flute_number + "\n" + RPM_dropdown + "\n" + generate_calculate_button();
      
      this.generate_results();// generate results container after page load could follow convention of insertion as the line above but good to know eithe way works

      let button_html = document.getElementById("calculateBut"); //getting the calculate button after its creation
      button_html.addEventListener("click", this.calculate.bind(this)); // binding call back function to scope of the class. not the callback function internal scope

    }

    render_content(){
   this.generatePage(this.populate_dropdown,this.generate_calculate_button);
      
    }

}
```

Comment: This sounds far more likely to be an issue with how you're binding/unbinding the events than some fundamental garbage collection issue, unless you're working with thousands of elements.

Comment: It's hard to diagnose what your exact issue is as you've not shown enough of the relevant code, however I can tell you that a ***far*** better approach to this problem is to use a delegated event handler for the dynamic content, ie. put the event handler on a static parent element in the DOM and let the events bubble up to it. Check in that event handler if it was raised by the element you want to target, and if so, then perform the necessary logic.

Comment: The event handler isn't going to be automatically removed (unless you pass a specific option to `addEventListener` to tell it to). My suspicion is that you're destroying and recreating the element(s) the listener is attached to (for instance, by assigning to `innerHTML` on its container); naturally, the new replacement element doesn't have any listeners on it to start with. But it's impossible to say for sure without more details.

Comment: Thanks to both for taking the time to answer my question, i really appreciate it. @T.J.Crowder I thought you might be on to something as i am doing a lot of that but im not editing the element that has the event listener on. take a look if you like, i added the rest of the code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan . you are completely right, i kind of knew about bubbling but i didnt really know what it was used for until now so thank you so much for that. this is my first project on the web.

Comment: @Lo_ - Please have a read through this help article: [mcve].

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the link, im sure you can tell im quite new to this. apologies. let me know if above is better?

Comment: Your `calculate` method doesn't really make sense. It does nothing but to add itself as an event listener once more. What should actually happen when you click the button?

Comment: @Bergi it does have more going on, however for the sake of the question I removed everything that wasn't relevant. Imagine it does some calculation as well as reapply an event listener